# Magento: how do I output current_category id from within tabs.phtml

Tags: php, magento, e-commerce

I've been able to output category and product data on most other template pages but I'm still unable to do so within tabs.phtml.  I have tried the follow, among many others - all without success:

```
$currentCategory = Mage::registry('current_category');
$currentCategoryId = $currentCategory['id'];
```

and

```
$currentCategoryId= Mage::getModel('catalog/category')->load($this->getCategoryId());
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
$currentCategory = Mage::registry('current_category');
$currentCategoryId = $currentCategory->getId();
```

or you can do like below

`$currentCategoryId = $currentCategory->getData('id');`

if the registry has the category session this will works.

Comment: Perfect, thanks for your help.  I'd actually tried these earlier but an error elsewhere in my code was preventing it from outputting correctly

Answer (score 0):

```
$currentCategory = Mage::registry('current_category');

var_dump($currentCategory->debug());
exit;
```

this will print currentcategory object. From this you can make out what all variables will be available by `getdata('variablename')`.

`$currentCategoryId = $currentCategory->getData('id');`

is surely going to work.

I suggested `->debug()` function as that function provides many more details and can be used for debugging and concluding when working with Magento.